# Telegram too many requests

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot, node-telegram-bot-api

I have been trying to create a mailing bot in telegram. I get a lot of 429 errors after some time, even though it sends only 8 messages a second which is a lot less than 30 a second (number which is allowed by telegram). Was wandering maybe it is because telegram tries to retry sending messages after unsuccessful request, so i get a lot of extra requests?

Comment: I did a litle pause between send, it worked

Comment: Is there a chance you are sending messages to a group chat? , because telegram got a 20 messages per min limit on group chats.